# Stripe PaymentMethod vs Card: Do I use default_source or default_payment_method?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am confused as to which do I use for checking if customer has set a payment method or source. Do I use `default_source` or `default_payment_method`?

I need to check if a customer has a payment method or source. If there's none, billing details form should be prompt until it gets set.

Found in stripe docs that the [Sources API is deprecated](https://stripe.com/docs/sources).

[The `default_source` is set when creating a card object and when there's no default card.](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create?lang=python).

I'm integrating stripe in my React-Python app and I'm confused if I should do first option : `stripe.Customer.card.create` which sets the `default_source` or if I do the 2nd option:

```
// stripe-react integration snippet
const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
  type: "card",
  card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
});

// python
payment_method = stripe.PaymentMethod.attach(
         payment_method_id,
         customer=stripe_customer_id,
    )

// set as default payment method
customer = stripe.Customer.modify(stripe_customer_id,
    invoice_settings={
        "default_payment_method": payment_method["id"]
    })
```

When I do the 2nd option, I can see the payment methods are set in the billing portal. It seems to do the job. Just confused when to use Card over PaymentMethod.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether a Customer has a default payment method or source configured, then you will want to check **both** the `default_source` field and the `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` fields on the Customer object. It is a valid state for a Customer to have a value set in both of those fields, in which case `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` is given priority.

For creating new Payment Methods, you should use Setup Intents and the approach outlined in the document linked below:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?type=setup

Alternatively you can use the flow shown here if you would prefer to use a Stripe-hosted page for collecting payment method details:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=checkout